# How do I center a mailchimp embed form in a twitter bootstrap page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here is the embed code.

```
     <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://unityi.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=a93bfac69d884f15e416661bb&amp;id=4618e101c1" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add center tags? I have tried it and it works. Simple answer :)

```
</style>

<!-- ADD HERE -->
**<center>**

<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://unityi.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?   u=a93bfac69d884f15e416661bb&amp;id=4618e101c1" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe- form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>

<!-- AND CLOSE HERE -->
**</center>**

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the attributes "display:block" and "margin:auto" should do it. You could also put the form in a grid, though that would be more complicated