# How to center Mailchimp sign-up form div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering, mailchimp

I've found this q&a on stack but both solutions did not work..

[How do I center a mailchimp embed form in a twitter bootstrap page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372206/how-do-i-center-a-mailchimp-embed-form-in-a-twitter-bootstrap-page)

[centering input in form mailchimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672482/centering-input-in-form-mailchimp)

What I think these questions lack is both the code for the form and style code included (see below). How can I center both the content (text) and the div itself as a whole so it's responsively centered on the page?

```
    <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>

    <center>
        <div class="display:block margin:auto "id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="//twitter.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=b59cd34816a376a0c58945aee&amp;id=2e74fec4e5" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
        <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_b59cd34816a376a0c58945aee_2e74fec4e5" tabindex="-1" value="">
            </div>
        <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>   
</form>
    </div>
</center>
```

You can see I've attempted the  tags as well as altering the class within the form..

Any help is greatly appreciated :3

Comment: For the future, please sort your code. It's easier to read for you and for us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using bootstrap. So how about wrapping that code inside the bootstrap's grid system.

```css
#mc_embed_signup {
  background: #fff;
  clear: left;
  font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <center>
        <div class="display:block margin:auto " id="mc_embed_signup">
          <form action="//twitter.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=b59cd34816a376a0c58945aee&amp;id=2e74fec4e5" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
            <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
              <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label><br />
              <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
              <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
              <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
                <input type="text" name="b_b59cd34816a376a0c58945aee_2e74fec4e5" tabindex="-1" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I 'run code snippet' it looks and makes sense.. however when copying into my code the input and button remain 'to the left' any ideas?

Comment: @jimmyNames Did you use the exact code from above to yours ? Do you have the live url of your work?

Comment: Here's the present state of my code http://codepen.io/Jimmynames/pen/xwGzXX I tried beforehand, copying your code but nothing.. will try again now though and let you know if it changes..

Comment: @jimmyNames Here's your updated pen : http://codepen.io/tusharkhatiwada/pen/xwGyyY . Does this help?

Comment: omg! Imma study your update and find out how you did it! Thankyou! :D

Comment: @jimmyNames Great. If that worked, please mark this post as answered :).

Comment: It looks like it worked on your codepen but when importing to Brackets it hasn't centered.. :/ See my twitter for example of the image against your solution https://twitter.com/J___Ryan/status/641531200633479168

Comment: Hi Tushar, just wanted to thank you again - this was correct/worked.. it seems bracketts live preview isn't the same as opening the html file in chrome..

Answer (score 2):

First - remove center tags and this "class":

```
class="display:block margin:auto"
```

Second - you can set input width to 100% and block width to 58%:

```
#mc_embed_signup input.email {
  ...
  width: 100%;
  ...
}

#mc_embed_signup form {
  ...
  width: 58%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Example:

```html
<link href="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
  #mc_embed_signup label {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #mc_embed_signup input.email {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #mc_embed_signup input.button {
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  #mc_embed_signup form {
    width: 58%;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>

<div class="display:block margin:auto" id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="//twitter.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=b59cd34816a376a0c58945aee&amp;id=2e74fec4e5" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
            <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
                <input type="text" name="b_b59cd34816a376a0c58945aee_2e74fec4e5" tabindex="-1" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Also, this looks like ugly hack:

```
style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"
```

Why u don't use hidden input or "display: none"? :)

Comment: When I 'run code snippet' it looks and makes sense.. however when copying into my code the input and button remain 'to the left' any ideas? Also the 'hack' was from Mailchimp's original code ;)

Comment: @jimmyNames did you add styles for "#mc_embed_signup label" and "#mc_embed_signup input.button" too?

Comment: Hey I've uploaded a copy of my present code on codepen (http://codepen.io/Jimmynames/pen/xwGzXX) can you see when I removed that 'hack' there's now a input(?) behind the button :s

Answer (score 0):

This article may help: [Customize Your Own MailChimp E-Mail Newsletter Signup Form](http://designshack.net/articles/css/custom-mailchimp-email-signup-form/).

```css
/** MailChimp Styles **/

#mc_embed_signup {
  background: #fff;
  clear: left;
  font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* MailChimp Form Embed Code - Slim - 08/17/2011 */

#mc_embed_signup form {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 3%;
}
#mc_embed_signup h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
#mc_embed_signup input {
  border: 1px solid #ababab;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=radio] {
  -webkit-appearance: radio;
}
#mc_embed_signup input:focus {
  border-color: #799877;
}
#mc_embed_signup .button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #266080;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#mc_embed_signup .button:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
}
#mc_embed_signup .button:active {
  top: 2px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
#mc_embed_signup .small-meta {
  font-size: 11px;
}
#mc_embed_signup .nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#mc_embed_signup .clear {
  clear: none;
  display: inline;
}
#mc_embed_signup label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  color: #616161;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#mc_embed_signup input.email {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  margin: 0 4% 10px 0;
  text-indent: 5px;
  color: #818181;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#mc_embed_signup input.email:focus {
  color: #666;
}
#mc_embed_signup div#mce-responses {
  float: left;
  top: -1.4em;
  padding: 0em .5em 0em .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  clear: both;
}
#mc_embed_signup div.response {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em .5em .5em 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  top: -1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 80%;
}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-error-response {
  display: none;
}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-success-response {
  color: #529214;
  display: none;
}
#mc_embed_signup label.error {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 1.05em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: .5em 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="//twitter.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=b59cd34816a376a0c58945aee&amp;id=2e74fec4e5" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
      <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email form-control" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
        <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
          <input type="text" name="b_b59cd34816a376a0c58945aee_2e74fec4e5" tabindex="-1" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is great for styling.. my input box and button still appear to the left however..

Comment: I can only assume there are other CSS rules on the page that are overriding the position then. I would use a dev toot to inspect the page if you haven't all ready.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying! Can you recommend a dev tool? I'm super new to this and your helps greatly appreciated

Comment: One way to do this is when you are previewing/viewing the page inside a browser such as Chrome/Firefox, right click on the page (or the specific element on the page you're working with) and select Inspect Element. For Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools or Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector

Answer (score 0):

I only got it to work when I changed your code in the CSS stylesheet to:

```
#mc_embed_signup {
    border-radius: 12%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 58%;
}
```